# How to reference an HTML element in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my `cshtml` page I have a select element with multiple options. Below it I have a button which needs the value of the selected option. How do I reference the value of the selected option?

```
<select>
  <option value="1">1</select>
  <option value="2">2</select>
  <option value="3">3</select>
</select>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { property = (how do i reference our selected option value here?)})'"
```

Comment: Better to submit as a form than try to use a hyperlink

Comment: you would usually use a form with a model and pass that model back to the action

Comment: as you look to be making a get url with js, why not just give your select a name of property and make your form method get